# How do you modify columns viewed in List item?

Tags: 2007, list

I know how to modify the columns displayed for a list, and for creating/editing an item, but how do you modify the columns that are displayed when you go 'into' an item.

I have a Tasks list, and when I click on one of the Task items, I'd like to restrict what's displayed to the columns that I want to display, i.e. I don't want to show background calculated fields, like ContentCalc and Summary in the view below.

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/560/taskitem.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/560/taskitem.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way: [create a custom list view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx) with SharePoint Designer 2007.

Comment: Wow, it's sure not easy, there's a ton of bug reports out there and I hosed my list.  Starting over and trying again.

Comment: Working with SharePoint Designer 2007 for the first time can be tricky but you are on the right path. If you have some specific questions post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is also part of the requirements but I believe you would still have to apply some security trimming to the columns in that view for the appropriate audience.  Check this article out
[link](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/09/17/custom-form-edit-fields-based-on-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-screencast/)

Comment: No, I don't have to worry about any user permission requirements.